# Aggregate function GROUP_CONCAT in MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I use the MySQL GROUP_CONCAT function is an aggregate function that concatenates strings from a group into a single string with various options for this return

```
'31A', '31C', '32B', '32D', '52G'
```

This is the query:

```
SELECT 
  GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT CONCAT( '''', xCOD ) ORDER BY xCOD ASC SEPARATOR ''' , ' ) AS x_group 
FROM `xtbl`
ORDER BY xCod ASC;
```

This returns:

```
'31A', '31C', '32B', '32D', '52G
```

But on the return the last element of MySQL GROUP_CONCAT function don't have the single quote

How to do resolve this?

Comment: What is your question? There is none here, which makes your post really unclear.

Comment: @GMB thanks can't add on this question the code of my query. Error submitted question. I have added query code image... An error occurred submitting the edit.

Comment: You can always add a quote if you need it at the end, using `CONCAT()`.

Comment: @IterLsicIealf Don't post an _image_.  Post your query (and results) as *text*.

Comment: @RocketHazmat thanksI  can't add on this question the code of my query. Error submitted question. I have added query code image.. An error occurred submitting the edit.

Comment: So, you're trying to wrap _each_ value in quotes?  Just do `CONCAT("'", xCOD, "'")`.  Then you can just use `SEPARATOR ", "`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to wrap each value in quotes, then you can just use `CONCAT` for this.

```
SELECT 
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT("'", xCOD, "'") ORDER BY xCOD ASC SEPARATOR ", ") AS x_group 
FROM `xtbl`
ORDER BY xCod ASC;
```

In fact, you don't even need `CONCAT` here at all.  You can just do:

```
SELECT 
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT "'", xCOD, "'" ORDER BY xCOD ASC SEPARATOR ", ") AS x_group 
FROM `xtbl`
ORDER BY xCod ASC;
```